# How to order columns specifically using r

Tags: r

I have this table x and y like this

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.6 | 0.2 |
| 0.8 | 0.2 |
| 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 0.4 | 0.2 |
| 0.6 | 0.4 |
| 0.8 | 0.4 |
| 0.2 | 0.4 |
| 0.4 | 0.4 |
| 0.6 | 0.8 |
| 0.8 | 0.8 |
| 0.2 | 0.8 |
| 0.4 | 0.8 |
| 0.6 | 0.6 |
| 0.8 | 0.6 |
| 0.2 | 0.6 |
| 0.4 | 0.6 |

- The question is how to order the table using r to be like below?

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 0.2 | 0.4 |
| 0.4 | 0.2 |
| 0.4 | 0.4 |
| 0.4 | 0.6 |
| 0.6 | 0.4 |
| 0.6 | 0.6 |
| 0.6 | 0.8 |
| 0.8 | 0.6 |
| 0.8 | 0.8 |

if somebody knows please,

- I tried to use the command order but it just order in two ways increasing and decreasing.

Comment: Please provide more detail in how you want them to be ordered, it is not clear. And also provide code to recreate your dataset

Comment: @jpsmith you can use `datapasta::tribble_construct` to recreate the dataset

Comment: You can use `dplyr::arrange(data,x)` to sort by ascending values of x. However, your example output has 2 rows in which x is 0.2, but your input has 4 rows. Do you want to do some filtering of rows as well?

Comment: *"I tried to use the command order but it just order in two ways increasing and decreasing."* It looks like you want it increasing, first by x then by y??? `data[order(data$x, data$y), ]`.

Comment: @danlooo Hi, I need to be ordered like the second table in which x  and y start with the smallest point 0.2 then use the second point 0.4 which will be  0.2 and 0.4 then 0.4 and 0.2 then when x and y are 0.4. After that, when x and y are 0.4 then use the third point 0.6 which will be  0.4 and 0.6 then 0.6 and 0.4 then when x and y are 0.6...